# How to get the menu id on href click in a page wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, submenu

i want the menu id on href click in wordpress because i'm using the menu id dynamically to list the submenus as childrens

```
<?php 
$menu=$wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT post_id FROM '.$wpdb->postmeta.' WHERE meta_key="_menu_item_object_id" AND meta_value="'.$post_id.'"' );
$args = array(
'menu'    => 'main',
'submenu' => (string) $menu
);

wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function custom_walker_nav_menu_start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args){
      $output = '<div class="buttons-'.$item->ID.'" title="some_title">';
      $output .= $item_output;
      $output .= '</div>';
      return $output;
    }
    add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'custom_walker_nav_menu_start_el' , 10, 4 );

 $menu_middle_left = array(
            'theme_location' => 'middle-left',
            'menu' => '',
            'container' => '',
            'container_class' => '',
            'container_id' => '',
            'menu_class' => '',
            'menu_id' => '',
            'echo' => true,
            'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
            'link_before' => '',
            'link_after' => '',
            'walker' => new Walker_Nav_Menu()
        );

        wp_nav_menu($menu_middle_left);
```

Comment: I want the menuId that i clicked in the page is it possible? @vimal Arya

Comment: I have modified my answer use walker class and the function i posted above hope it works for you